# Passing List<classname> to ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android

The problem is this adapter is giving the error although i have pass the Object array to it.(Read the methods belows then you will find what i want to know from you guys)

This method declares a List of private class objects. Then return that list of object to onPostExecute method.

```
private class DownloadXmlTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {

            return loadXmlFromNetwork(urls[0]);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "I/O exception ae hy";
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            return "XML pull parser ke exception ae hy";
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<StackOverflowXmlParser.Entry> result) {
        //Log.d(TAG,result.toString());
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,result);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private Object loadXmlFromNetwork(String urlString) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        InputStream stream = null;
        // Instantiate the parser
        StackOverflowXmlParser stackOverflowXmlParser = new StackOverflowXmlParser();
        List<StackOverflowXmlParser.Entry> entries = null;
        String title = null;
        String url = null;
        String summary = null;


        try {
            stream = downloadUrl(urlString);
            entries = stackOverflowXmlParser.parse(stream);

        } finally {
            if (stream != null) {
                stream.close();
            }
        }
        for (StackOverflowXmlParser.Entry entry : entries)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, entry.link + " /" + entry.title);
        }

            return entries;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be `onPostExecute(List<StackOverflowXmlParser.Entry> result)`

And you AsyncTask should be

`extends AsyncTask<smth, smth, List<StackOverflowXmlParser.Entry> >`

Comment: I have edit the question and posted that class.. Please check the class and please let me know where and what should i do

Comment: To be more precise , i have followed this tutorial : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

Now i want that entries populates in the list view

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayAdapter<String>` requires that you provide it a `String[]` or a `List<String>`. You are trying to pass in `Object[]`, which is neither `String[]` nor `List<String>`. And, it would appear that you are really trying to populate the `ListView` with a list of `StackOverflowXmlParser.Entry` objects, which are not `String` objects.

My guess is that the right answer is for you to create an `ArrayAdapter<StackOverflowXmlParser.Entry>` instead of an `ArrayAdapter<String>`.

Regardless, you need to ensure that the data type in your declaration (`String` in `ArrayAdapter<String>`) matches the data type in your constructor parameter that supplies the data to be adapted.

Comment: Error is still here. 
Actually i parse the xml,get the link and title tag from each post. That link and title are declared in Entry class.
     entries = stackOverflowXmlParser.parse(stream);     gets that list and i am sending it to onPostExuecte.
From there ,i want to populate the list view.

So what should i do in onPostExecute()

Comment: @user3585510: It looks like you have more than one error; see Alex's answer for another one that I missed originally.

Comment: To be more precise , i have followed this tutorial : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

Now i want that entries populates in the list view